# Advantages and disadvantages of using more middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using middlewares for my Laravel application and sometimes I have to add four or five middlewares in each controller. I am interested to know advantages and disadvantages of using more middlewares in any controller. I'll be thankful if anyone can guide me about this topic.

Comment: middleware is used to controll the http request only

Comment: I think it would be more useful to know what you are trying to achieve exactly? Pros & cons are too generic, they need to be contextual. So kindly rephrase your question and be more specific about your end goal and then maybe you will receive better quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware works on the request layer of the application layer.
Middleware works like a door or entry point for your application. You need to look out for who can come into the application or who can not by writing a logic in the middleware and then apply it on the requests. Same like a guard won't come into your drawing room to identify who is a valid visitor. He does that on the door :)
Middleware reduces redundancy in your code. Like you need to look out for some type of validations for user's post and you write a middleware for that then no need to validate same thing anywhere in the `PostController` or in any other class. So if the `user` is not a valid application user, application will reject him right away on the entry point and wont let him in.

Comment: thanks@Muhammad Nauman for answering me. I know what is the middleware and its work in application. Kindly read my question again. My question is about the number of middlewares we use in an application. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using more than one middlewares.

Comment: well i don`t know advantages or disadvantages but you can use many middlewares with no limit or you can handle it with one for related routes